# How can I develop a WordPress website with "floating" sidebar like Brit.co?

Tags: wordpress

If you go to Brit.co, you'll notice the sidebar container floats inside the main page container. This allows main page content that is below sidebar content, to wrap under the sidebar.

Explain in different way: A super high WordPress website, say 3,000 px in height, where the sidebar is only 1,000 px high, there is 2,000px of white space under the sidebar container. I'm trying to eliminate that.

Now, I can add container (e.g. footer) under both main content and sidebar wrappers (DIVs), but this is not being done at brit.co.

Sorry, this has us baffled. Normally not an issue b/c our WordPress sites are not that high. Would like to know if there are easy solutions!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like it's just `float:right` in `CSS`?

Comment: I don't think it's a positioning issue, but a wrapping issue.

Comment: Sorry, I get in the habit of posting insurmountable questions. I found a good work-a-round, actually better that what I had hoped. Still driving me crazy not knowing exactly how to structure that brit.co website. Cheers!